# Create dynamic rectangle/box using easelJs or KineticJs

Tags: javascript, kineticjs, fabricjs, easeljs, paperjs

Hi I am looking to make a floor plan editor (something like MsPaint) using JavaScript. I have shortlisted **EaselJS** or **KinetiJS** as my preferred libraries.

I would like to know how to **create a dynamic rectangular box/line** with these libraries. I intend to draw a rectangle by clicking the mouse and dragging it (while the mouse button remains pressed). Thus the size of the rectangle will depend on how far the mouse is dragged.

Any help will be appreciated. If anyone feels that any other library like **fabrisJs** or **paperJs** will be better alternative then I am open to solutions in these libraries as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok... by trial and error and lots of googling and reusing net code I got the answer for KineticJs.

Heres the complete solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/sandeepy02/8kGVD/

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            window.onload = function() {
                layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
                stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
                    container: "container",
                    width: 320,
                    height: 320
                });

                background = new Kinetic.Rect({
                    x: 0, 
                    y: 0, 
                    width: stage.getWidth(),
                    height: stage.getHeight(),
                    fill: "white"
                });


                layer.add(background);
                stage.add(layer);

                moving = false;

                stage.on("mousedown", function(){
                    if (moving){
                        moving = false;layer.draw();
                    } else {
                        var mousePos = stage.getMousePosition();
                        rect= new Kinetic.Rect({
        x: 22,
        y: 7,
        width: 0,
        height: 0,
        fill: 'red',
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 4
                        });
                        layer.add(rect);
                        //start point and end point are the same
                        rect.setX(mousePos.x);
                        rect.setY(mousePos.y);
                        rect.setWidth(0);
                        rect.setHeight(0);


                        moving = true;    
                        layer.drawScene();            
                    }

                });

                stage.on("mousemove", function(){
                    if (moving) {
                        var mousePos = stage.getMousePosition();
                        var x = mousePos.x;
                        var y = mousePos.y;
                        rect.setWidth(mousePos.x-rect.getX());
                        rect.setHeight(mousePos.y-rect.getY());
                        moving = true;
                        layer.drawScene();
                    }
                });

                stage.on("mouseup", function(){
                    moving = false; 
                });

            };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container" ></div>
    </body>
</html>
​
```

Comment: suggestion, if you want to resize the rect afterwards use a small circle and display it in the corner where the mouse is, then use the draggble feature of the circle to resize the rect.